# openvpn does not change DNS server

Tags: 18.04, dns, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to set up a VPN on Ubuntu 18.04.3. Following the suggestions on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107704/openvpn-not-changing-ip-address/1107830?noredirect=1#comment1961499_1107830), I added the following lines to the end of the .ovpn file:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

I also ran

```
sudo rm -i /etc/resolv.conf

sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

to fix /etc/resolv.conf.

Then I created the VPN under VPN Settings -> Add VPN -> Open from File, and used the .ovpn file.

However, when I turn the VPN on, the computer still uses the local DNS server, rather than that of the VPN.

Here are the results of various diagnostics, with the VPN on and off:

### ---------------------------VPN off:------------------------------

cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf:

`No such file or directory`

cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver fd08:b55d:5917:0:3e89:94ff:fe31:c148
search Home
```

cat /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search Home
```

systemd-resolve --status:

```
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (wlp59s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1
                      fd08:b55d:5917:0:3e89:94ff:fe31:c148
          DNS Domain: Home
```

cat /etc/network/interfaces:

```
 # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

### ----------------------------VPN on:------------------------------

cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf:

```
No such file or directory
```

cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver fd08:b55d:5917:0:3e89:94ff:fe31:c148
nameserver 10.34.16.1
search Home
```

cat /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search Home
```

systemd-resolve --status:

```
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 8 (tun0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 10.34.16.1

Link 2 (wlp59s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1
                      fd08:b55d:5917:0:3e89:94ff:fe31:c148
          DNS Domain: Home
```

cat /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

EDIT:

ls -al /sbin/resolvconf outputs `ls: cannot access '/sbin/resolvconf': No such file or directory`.

With the VPN off, `host -v www.ebay.com` outputs:

```
Trying "www.ebay.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12728
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.ebay.com.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.ebay.com.       60  IN  CNAME   slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net.
slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net. 60 IN    CNAME   e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.
e9428.b.akamaiedge.net. 60  IN  A   104.78.177.101

Received 122 bytes from 192.168.0.1#53 in 14 ms
Trying "e9428.b.akamaiedge.net"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 881
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.        IN  AAAA

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
b.akamaiedge.net.   996 IN  SOA n0b.akamaiedge.net. hostmaster.akamai.com. 1568976151 1000 1000 1000 1800

Received 101 bytes from 192.168.0.1#53 in 12 ms
Trying "e9428.b.akamaiedge.net"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 30223
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.        IN  MX

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
b.akamaiedge.net.   1000    IN  SOA n0b.akamaiedge.net. hostmaster.akamai.com. 1568976180 1000 1000 1000 1800

Received 101 bytes from 192.168.0.1#53 in 13 ms
```

With the VPN on:

```
Trying "www.ebay.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 7665
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.ebay.com.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.ebay.com.       60  IN  CNAME   slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net.
slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net. 60 IN    CNAME   e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.
e9428.b.akamaiedge.net. 60  IN  A   104.78.177.101

Received 122 bytes from 192.168.0.1#53 in 15 ms
Trying "e9428.b.akamaiedge.net"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 1414
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.        IN  AAAA

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
b.akamaiedge.net.   999 IN  SOA n0b.akamaiedge.net. hostmaster.akamai.com. 1568976217 1000 1000 1000 1800

Received 101 bytes from 192.168.0.1#53 in 12 ms
Trying "e9428.b.akamaiedge.net"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 6348
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.        IN  MX

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
b.akamaiedge.net.   994 IN  SOA n0b.akamaiedge.net. hostmaster.akamai.com. 1568976219 1000 1000 1000 1800

Received 101 bytes from 192.168.0.1#53 in 19 ms
```

EDIT 2: After running `sudo apt-get install resolvconf`, the output of `host -v www.ebay.com`, with the VPN on, becomes:

```
Trying "www.ebay.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9033
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.ebay.com.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.ebay.com.       60  IN  CNAME   slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net.
slot9428.ebay.com.edgekey.net. 59 IN    CNAME   e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.
e9428.b.akamaiedge.net. 59  IN  A   104.78.177.101

Received 122 bytes from 127.0.0.53#53 in 57 ms
Trying "e9428.b.akamaiedge.net"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 19716
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.        IN  AAAA

Received 40 bytes from 127.0.0.53#53 in 15 ms
Trying "e9428.b.akamaiedge.net"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 48908
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;e9428.b.akamaiedge.net.        IN  MX

Received 40 bytes from 127.0.0.53#53 in 21 ms
```

EDIT 3:

The output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` is the same, and is:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search Home
```

EDIT 4: Calling `grep -r '192.168.0.1' /etc/` returns:

```
/etc/sane.d/saned.conf:#192.168.0.1
/etc/sane.d/saned.conf:#192.168.0.1/29
/etc/sane.d/magicolor.conf:# net 192.168.0.1
/etc/avahi/hosts:# 192.168.0.1 router.local
```

With the VPN turned on via the Network Manager GUI (i.e., from the top menu), the output of `systemd-resolve --status` is:

```
Global
          DNS Domain: Home
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 13 (tun0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 10.34.40.1

Link 2 (wlp59s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1
                      fd08:b55d:5917:0:3e89:94ff:fe31:c148
          DNS Domain: Home
```

Calling the VPN via `sudo openvpn` seems to work correctly: The output of `systemd-resolve --status` is:

```
Global
         DNS Servers: 10.34.48.1
          DNS Domain: Home
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 14 (tun0)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no

Link 2 (wlp59s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1
                      fd08:b55d:5917:0:3e89:94ff:fe31:c148
          DNS Domain: Home
```

dnsleak.com shows the VPN's DNS server, and `host -v www.ebay.com` gets its data from 10.34.48.1.

Two interesting output lines from the initialization of the VPN from the terminal are:

```
/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf tun0 1500 1553 10.34.48.8 255.255.252.0 init
dhcp-option DNS 10.34.48.1
```

It looks like maybe the `openvpn` command is changing the `dhcp-option`, but the network manager is not.

Comment: Actually... **it does**.  `DNS Servers: 10.34.16.1` Each link in SystemD's ResolveD can carry its own assigned DNS servers, it uses them in the order shown from first link to last (first come first tested) through to the end to run DNS queries.  It won't change the DNS entries in resolv.conf, no, but that's becuase the resolv.conf points at `systemd-resolved` which handles DNS queries outbound internally to itself.

Comment: Thanks for copying over all of the data from our previous discussion. Show me `ls -al /sbin/resolvconf` and with vpn down/up `host -v www.ebay.com`.

Comment: I added the two other outputs. It looks like it's still not using the new DNS server because the 192.168.0.1 is still first, so I'm still getting DNS leaks.

Comment: Make sure to start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll surely miss them. Thanks for the updates to my questions. Install this `sudo apt-get install resolvconf`, then reboot, and retry the `systemd-resolve --status` command with vpn up. Recheck the `host -v` command, and check for DNS leaks. Report back.

Comment: @ThomasWard actually, it's **not** working correctly, as seen by the `host -v` command, and the dns leaks.

Comment: to make systemd-resolved only use link dns you need to set/prefix dns domain with ~ https://goyoambrosio.com/2018/06/Preventing-DNS-Leaks-in-VPNs/

Comment: @bac0n if you review the data provided by the user, you'll notice that the DNS servers identified are 1) incorrect, and 2) in the wrong order. Your linked article shouldn't be required to stop DNS leaks.

Comment: @heynnema I installed and rebooted; systemd-resolve --status gives the same output except (1) the first line, before "DNSSEC NTA", is "DNS Domain: Home" (2) "Link 8 (tun0)" became "Link 4 (tun0)" (3) The DNS server with a hex address (ipv6?) for Link 2 (wlp59s0) is gone. Also, dnsleak.com now shows two outputs: One which is the VPN's DNS server, and another from the ISP's DNS server.

Comment: @SamJaques Are you using the OpenVPN CLI to connect to VPN, or the NetworkManager GUI to connect to VPN? You've modified your .ovpn file, yes? Did you import it into NM again, after the mods? With VPN up, show me `cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`, `cat /etc/resolv.conf`, `host -v www.ebay.com`, and `systemd-resolve --status`.

Comment: @SamJaques and `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: tcpdump -i tun0 udp port 53

Comment: @heynnema I'm using the NetworkManager GUI, and I modified the .ovpn file. I tried deleting and re-importing just now (and removing a VPN configuration connecting to the same server, but without the changes). `host -v www.ebay.com` and `systemd-resolve --status` haven't changed. I'll add the others to the question.

Comment: @bac0n I tried adding `domain ~.` (from the article you linked) but I wasn't sure how; the command they wrote gives the error `Failed to parse number of array entries: . ` (to be fair, I didn't understand the D-bus section at all). Based on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322883/how-to-correctly-set-hostname-and-domain-name I added a line to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`, which didn't fix the issue, so I removed the line.  What am I looking for with the tcpdump?

Comment: @SamJaques The reason that I asked for `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` is that I believe that the installation of resolvconf may have changed this symlink... which may be ok. Otherwise, I'm looking for where 192.168.0.1 is manually defined. Did you add this to the DNS field in the ipv4 tab for your wireless connection? Or add it to any (.conf) files elsewhere in /etc? With VPN up, show me `systemd-resolve --status` again. Try this `sudo openvpn your_filename.ovpn` and then check `systemd-resolve --status` and see if the only DNS server is 10.x.x.x.

Answer (score 0):

## DNSoverTLS 1.1.1.1 OpenVPN configuration.

First you need systemd-resolved installed and configured to use stub-resolv.conf.

```
ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

**Output**

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

## systemd-networkd

## /etc/systemd/resolved.conf (example):

```
[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
FallbackDNS=1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1
LLMNR=no
MulticastDNS=no
DNSSEC=allow-downgrade
DNSOverTLS=opportunistic
Cache=yes
DNSStubListener=yes
```

## /etc/systemd/network/ethX.network (example):

```
[Match]
Name=eth*

[Link]
RequiredForOnline=yes

[Network]
DHCP=yes
MulticastDNS=no
LLMNR=no
LinkLocalAddressing=no

[DHCP]
UseDNS=yes
UseHostname=no
CriticalConnection=yes
```

## /etc/systemd/network/tunX.network (important!):

(in order for openvpn to be able to administer tun link, the link must be unmanaged)

```
[Match]
Name=tun*

[Link]
Unmanaged=yes
```

I use [update-resolved](https://github.com/bac0n/update-resolved) to configure systemd-resolved.
(you can use [update-systemd-resolved](https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved) or 
aptitude install openvpn-systemd-resolved, but when you need to follow
[README.md](https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved/blob/master/README.md) instead).

## Installing update-resolved:

```
cd /etc/openvpn
git clone https://github.com/bac0n/update-resolved.git
```

## Add update-resolved to your openvpn.conf:

```
# Include update-resolved up/down script.
config /etc/openvpn/update-resolved/update-resolved.ovpn
```

## Restart openvpn:

```
systemctl restart openvpn
```

## Journald:

```
journalctl -t update-resolved
```

**Output**

```
-- Logs begin at Sat 2019-09-21 12:28:01 CEST, end at Sun 2019-09-22 17:05:01 CEST. --
Sep 21 12:28:11 foobar update-resolved[914]: Note: Successfully configured resolved on link 3 (tun0)
```

## Note:

As default it uses openvpn supplied dns´s. if you like to use
static dns´s you need to filter the dns´s supplied by openvpn
in 'update-resolved.ovpn' and set your own dns´s in 'update-resolved.conf'

## Example:

```
resolve_options=(DOMAIN ~. DNS 1.1.1.1 DNS 1.0.0.1 LLMNR no MulticastDNS no)
```

(when using domain ~. resolved will use the tun link for all your dns queries (unless other too carry such a route-only domain). When the tun link is removed resolved will start using 'global' and 'isp' dns´s in parallel, [Protocols and Routing](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html#Protocols%20and%20Routing))

Comment: systemd is installed and the /etc/resolv.conf link is fixed. For both /etc/systemd/network/ethX.network and /etc/systemd/network/tunX.network, I get "No such file or directory". Are those files important to have?

Comment: no, you can check if your tun interface is unmanaged with ```networkctl```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it seems a script possible your current update-resolv-conf is overriding /etc/resolv.conf directly and causing a dead link, we can fix that in your up and down script.  Based on your question you want /etc/resolv.conf to be linked to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf, not the systemd resolv.conf.  You should have two scripts one when openvpn connects, and one when it disconnects, so modify your vpn config slight to:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf-up
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf-down
```

You will need to add +x permission to both update-resolv-conf-up and update-resolv-conf-down after you create them.

/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf-up

```
#!/bin/sh

cat <<EOF > /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
nameserver 10.34.48.1
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver fd08:b55d:5917:0:3e89:94ff:fe31:c148
search Home
EOF

rm /etc/resolv.conf 
ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

and
/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf-down

```
#!/bin/sh
cat <<EOF > /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver fd08:b55d:5917:0:3e89:94ff:fe31:c148
search Home
EOF
```

The /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf-up script ensure the nameserver 127.0.0.53 is the first nameserver, ensuring that it is used by DNS when resolving addresses, when the vpn is connected, the 10.34.48.1 becomes the second dns, with 192.168.0.1 always being the last dns.